# How to make a user locale sticke during a user session in Symfony 6?

Tags: php, symfony

I tried to follow the information in the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html) to make a user local sticky during the users session by using a `UserLocaleSubscriber`.

The example code from the docs uses the `InteractiveLoginEvent` which seems to be deprecated in Symfony 6 and `LoginSuccessEvent` should be used instead. No matter which event I use in my code (both events are fired when using the login form), the local

```
class UserLocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    private $requestStack;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array {
        return [
            //SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onInteractiveLogin',
            LoginSuccessEvent::class => 'onLoginSuccess'
        ];
    }

    public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event): void {
        ...
    }

    public function onLoginSuccess(LoginSuccessEvent $event) {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticatedToken()->getUser();
        $locale = $user->getLocale();
        $this->logger->info("onLoginSuccess: $locale");

        if (null !== $locale) {
            $this->logger->info("      set");
            $this->requestStack->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
            $event->getRequest()->setLocale($locale);
        }
    }
}


// Log
onLoginSuccess: de [] {"url":"/login",...}
    set [] {"url":"/login",...}
UserLocaleSubscriber [] {"url":"/restrictedPage",...}
```

So, the event subscribers are correctly called when handling the login page and the locale is set to the session. However, on the next request when redirecting to the restricted page, no event is fired, and thus the locale is not applied. So here the default fallback locale is used. But shouldn't be the locale correctly in the session at this point?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer. I will leave the question in place in case someone else stumbles over the same problem:

In fact the code from the question is correct and **does** add the local to the session. However, the translator **does NOT** load the locale from the session but from the current request. So the locale is stored correctly but not used...

To solve this, one has to add a request listener which checks the session for a locale and add it to the request. This is described in [the docs linked in the question](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html#creating-a-localesubscriber). I got this wrong and though one has to implement one OR the other when in fact both listeners are needed.